# Xpages and JMeter

Tags: jmeter, xpages

I am creating a script in JMeter to evaluate an application on xpages. The business flow is as follows:

1. Login to Domino
2. Choose an option on the page that is displayed in the
   application
3. Click a button to submit the chosen option and generate
   a document.

The script runs smoothly until the button is clicked; subsequent actions are not working as expected.

The button basically has two nested action groups **each with a condition**, and an **Execute Script** where the data is actually submitted and the Notes document is created.

What I noticed, is that no code (conditions and script) of the button are executed.

Has anyone had this problem with JMeter? Would you help me?

Comment: After clicking on that button, a document will be generated correct? How the document is opening? Within the browser or asking you to save it.

Comment: Marcus, which sampler(s) are you using to do the job?

Comment: Correct, but I create the document in the background. It is not displayed, after the click of the button, there is a redirect to another xpage.

Comment: I actually do not use a sample. I use a Group thread, an HTTP proxy server, and a record controller.

Comment: Create a small sample app to demo the problem. Provide both the XPage and the JMeter script here. Until you do so it is anybody's Guess what you did, especially since buttons depend on JS and jMeter deals with protocol only

Comment: I believe that the action is pure client-side, that is the reason why JMeter is not replaying. You need to post the samplers request/response.

Comment: No, action is SSJS only.